# Prove that there exists a field K and a polynomial f(x) ∈ K[x] for which f(t) = 0 for all t ∈ K but f(x) NOT ≡ 0.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Prove that there exists a field K and a polynomial f(x) ∈ K[x]
for which f(t) = 0 for all t ∈ K but f(x) NOT ≡ 0.

[image]

I can't figure out how to prove this - any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Consider $K=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and Fermat's little theorem

Comment: Let $K = \mathbb{F}_2$ and $f(x) = x^2+x$. Then $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: Note $K$ has to be a finite field. No polynomial of finite degree with coefficients in $K$ can have infinitely many roots unless the polynomial itself is $0$ i.e. $f(x) = 0$, as no polynomial can have more roots than its degree.

Answer (score 1):

Let $K=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and let $f(x)=x^p-x$.

Then $f(t)=0$ for all $t\in K$ by Fermat's little theorem,

but $f(x)$ is not identically the zero polynomial.